# A way to view all S3 object upload/pulled on a certain date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket and need to find out a way to see all the actions happened to my bucket objects on a specific date. Something to help me trace and see a list of all the files which were uploaded or downloaded from my bucket on a certain date.
Thank you

Comment: I don't believe there is way of getting date of downloaded objects, but you can certainly check the upload time using python `boto3`

Comment: @wishmaster thank you, basically I am trying to find out what was happening to my bucket objects (uploading/downloading/deleting) on a certain date. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: @Tina only via either S3 access logs, or via cloudtrail, both which need to be configured prior to the event happening.

Comment: @jordanm I had already enabled the 3 access logs and had it send the logs to another s3 bucket. Checked that destination S3 bucket and that was empty.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to [enable object-level logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-cloudtrail-events.html) for the S3 bucket. Once that is done, you can [query the CloudTrail events](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/find-cloudtrail-object-level-events/) for read/write access to objects in a bucket.

Note: Object-level data access logging only starts once it is turned on. You can’t retroactively retrieve data access information for time periods when it wasn’t enabled.